# How to keep writing a block of text to a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I got a file, I want to be able to get the content of this file and write them x number of time to another file based on a provided number.

I got this code but I get written the content of my file only one time.....

`replace_num_array` is my number of time mentioned above.

```
def replace_lines(f, wf):
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        wf.write(line)


def copy_cust(f, wf, replace_num_array):
    for y in replace_num_array:
        replace_lines(f, wf)


def process_file(filename, writefile, tagname, rectype_whereTagNameGoes, tagname_whichrec_coordinates_findall, replace_coordinates_findall, replace_num_array):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
        with open(writefile, 'a+') as wf:
            copy_cust(f, wf, replace_num_array)
```

Any help is much appreciated, I am pretty new to Python, probably I am doing something quite silly here...

I don't get error with my code but I don't get copy X number of time, I think I am writing over the same contents :-)

Thanks,

Paolo

Comment: Each open file has a file pointer to remember where to read or write next. It moves when reading or writing is done. Your file to read from has the pointer at its end after it was read once.

Comment: `copy_cust(f, wf, replace_num_array)`  reads the file, after it you need to close/reopen it or seek() to its start again. See dupe.

Comment: Add the line `f.seek(0)` to the beginning of `replace_lines`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys....i understand now.....

Comment: I ended up going like this actually...it works.....is it decent code you think? the file am opening is small.....

Comment: def process_file(filename, writefile, tagname, rectype_whereTagNameGoes, tagname_whichrec_coordinates_findall, replace_coordinates_findall, replace_num_array):
    ClassFile = open(filename, 'r')
    filelines = list(ClassFile)
    # removing header
    filelines.pop(0)
    # removing trailer
    filelines.pop()
    with open(writefile, 'a') as wf:
        for i in replace_num_array:
            for line in filelines:
                wf.write(line)
        wf.close()